# CMake Error(Configure)

Tags: cmake

I have an issue with configuring CMake. How could I solve this error? Please somebody help us. The error is shown below.

[image]

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)
linked by target "openpose" in directory C:/Users/a0102/Documents/GitHub/openpose/src/openpose
CUDA_TOOLKIT_INCLUDE (ADVANCED)
used as include directory in directory C:/Users/a0102/Documents/GitHub/openpose/src/openpose
used as include directory in directory C:/Users/a0102/Documents/GitHub/openpose/examples/calibration
used as include directory in directory C:/Users/a0102/Documents/GitHub/openpose/examples/openpose
used as include directory in directory C:/Users/a0102/Documents/GitHub/openpose/examples/tutorial_add_module
used as include directory in directory C:/Users/a0102/Documents/GitHub/openpose/examples/tutorial_pose
used as include directory in directory C:/Users/a0102/Documents/GitHub/openpose/examples/tutorial_pose
used as include directory in directory C:/Users/a0102/Documents/GitHub/openpose/examples/tutorial_thread
used as include directory in directory C:/Users/a0102/Documents/GitHub/openpose/examples/tutorial_thread
used as include directory in directory C:/Users/a0102/Documents/GitHub/openpose/examples/tutorial_thread
used as include directory in directory C:/Users/a0102/Documents/GitHub/openpose/examples/tutorial_thread
used as include directory in directory C:/Users/a0102/Documents/GitHub/openpose/examples/tutorial_wrapper
used as include directory in directory C:/Users/a0102/Documents/GitHub/openpose/examples/tutorial_wrapper
used as include directory in directory C:/Users/a0102/Documents/GitHub/openpose/examples/tutorial_wrapper
used as include directory in directory C:/Users/a0102/Documents/GitHub/openpose/examples/tutorial_wrapper
used as include directory in directory C:/Users/a0102/Documents/GitHub/openpose/examples/tutorial_wrapper
used as include directory in directory C:/Users/a0102/Documents/GitHub/openpose/examples/tutorial_wrapper
```

Comment: Can you share the code that is causing the compilation to fail?

Comment: @mlapaglia 
Could NOT find CUDA (missing: CUDA_NVCC_EXECUTABLE CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY)
Building with CUDA.
Could NOT find CUDA (missing: CUDA_NVCC_EXECUTABLE CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY)
Downloading windows dependencies...
opencv_310.zip already exists.
caffe3rdparty_2018_02_13.zip already exists.
caffe_2018_01_18.zip already exists.

Comment: Windows dependencies downloaded.
Adding Example Calibration
Adding Example OpenPoseDemo
Adding Example 1_custom_post_processing
Adding Example 1_extract_from_image
Adding Example 2_extract_pose_or_heatmat_from_image
Adding Example 1_openpose_read_and_display
Adding Example 2_user_processing_function
Adding Example 3_user_input_processing_and_output
Adding Example 4_user_input_processing_output_and_datum
Adding Example 1_user_synchronous_postprocessing

Comment: Adding Example 2_user_synchronous_input
Adding Example 3_user_synchronous_output
Adding Example 4_user_synchronous_all
Adding Example 5_user_asynchronous
Adding Example 6_user_asynchronous_output

Comment: Download the models.
Not downloading BODY_25 model
Not downloading body (COCO) model
Not downloading body (MPI) model
Downloading face model...
Model already exists.
Downloading hand model...
Model already exists.
Models Downloaded.

Comment: CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)
linked by target "openpose" in directory C:/Users/a0102/Documents/GitHub/openpose/src/openpose
CUDA_TOOLKIT_INCLUDE (ADVANCED)

Comment: And the following error I wrote above

Comment: I downloaded CUDA 9.2 with visual studios 2017. Is this because of the version?

Comment: Do not use comments for multiline code - it looks ugly. Instead, [edit] the question and add the information into it.